# Can not select use case for Facebook's pages_messaging_subscriptions permission

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-messenger, review, facebook-chatbot

I'm building a small chat bot to get some experience in that area.
I'd like to apply for the pages_messaging_subscriptions permission on Facebook.
I already got through with the pages_messaging.

But when I try to enter the notes for the pages_messaging_subscriptions permission I'can't hit the save button. It seams that I have to select a use case, what I did, but they are somehow grayed out. Can someone please help. Maybe from Facebook? I already tried the developer community group without a solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to explain the FB team how your chat bot will use pages_messaging_subscriptions permission. You need to upload a screencapture video of your app that explains the use case.
There are some requirements to get this permission.

1. You need to give user a choice to subscribe and unsubscribe from getting the notifications.
2. You need to show what will happen after subscription how end user will get notification.
3. You need to show use case of how user will unsubscribe and how it affects the notification.

All this you need to include in one video and upload it there.
For your use case I think News is the correct category.